# ComboBox Selected Item refreshes page

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I am using an ajaxtoolkit Combo Box to select list items.  Each time I select an item the page gets refreshed.  I have set the autoposback to true.  How can I prevent this.  Below is my piece of html:

```
<ajaxToolkit:ComboBox ID="cmbDesignation" runat="server"
                         DropDownStyle="Simple" 
                         AutoCompleteMode="None" 
                         CaseSensitive="false" 
                         RenderMode="Inline" 
                         ItemInsertLocation="Append" AutoPostBack="True" Height="19px" Width="400px">
                       <asp:ListItem Value="0" Selected="True">--SelectItem--</asp:ListItem>
                                                 <asp:ListItem>Item1</asp:ListItem>
                                                 <asp:ListItem>Item2</asp:ListItem>

</ajaxToolkit:ComboBox>
```

Comment: Why do you set `AutoPostBack="True"` if you do not want the PostBack when an item is selected?

Comment: Does the page physically refresh (reload), or are you saying your page "updates" when you click the dropdown? If it reloads physically, make sure you are placing your controls inside an ajax update panel.

Comment: Once I select an Item the page was firing the refresh button and the mouse focus was not moving to the next control.  When AutoPostBack="False" the dropdownlist does not close upon selection of an item. I have used an update panel and it has helped. Thanks.